# Calculate Fourier transform and Fourier inverse of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

let the functions $f_{\alpha}(x)= e^{-\alpha x} H(x), \ \alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ where $H$ is function of Heaviside and $ g_a(x)= \begin{cases} 1 &: |x| < a\\ 0 &:|x|\geq a \end{cases}$.

The question is calculate Fourier of $f_{\alpha}$, Fourier of $g_a$, inverse Fourier of $f_{\alpha}$ and inverse Fourier of $g_a$.

I try this:
1. to calculate Fourier of $f_{\alpha}$: $F f_{\alpha}$ we have 
$$
F f_{\alpha}(\xi)= \displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} e^{- i x \xi} e^{-\alpha x} dx = -\dfrac{1}{i \xi + \alpha}.
$$
to calculer inverse of Fourier transform, we have 
$$
\overline{F} f_{\alpha}(x)= \displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} e^{i x \xi} e^{-\alpha \xi} d \xi = \displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} e^{\xi(ix - \alpha)} d\xi =\dfrac{1}{ix-\alpha} [e^{\xi(ix-\alpha)}]_0^{+\infty}
$$
but isn't converge, i have problem to determine the value of $\overline{F} f_{\alpha}(x)$.

2. To calculate Fourier of $g_a$ i find that $F g_a(\xi)=0$ if $\xi \neq 0$ and $Fg_a(0)= 2 a$.
   And to calculate $\overline{F}g_a(x)$ i find that $\overline{F} g_a(x)= 0$ if $x \neq 0$ and $\overline{F}g_a(0)=2a$. Is it correct? Please.

Thank you in advance to the help.

Comment: Why do you think that $\dfrac{1}{ix-\alpha} [e^{\xi(ix-\alpha)}]_0^{+\infty}$ diverges?  $|e^{\xi ix}| = 1$ and $\alpha > 0$

Comment: but when $\xi=+\infty$ what we found? Can you help me to right an correctly anwser please

Comment: $e^{-\alpha \xi} \to 0$ much quicker than $ix \to \infty$

Comment: Sorry i don't understand how we calculate. We have $e^{\xi(ix - \alpha)}= e^{i x \xi} e^{-\alpha \xi}$ when $\xi \to +\infty$ what's the limit of $e^{i x \xi}$? Please

Comment: You don't need to worry about this term as it's bounded, while the other factors tend to zero.

Comment: Then the result is $\overline{F}f_{\alpha}(x)= \dfrac{1}{ix-\alpha}$. is my solution true? Please

Comment: My bad: when I made the comment "$e^{-\alpha \xi} \to 0$ ...", I mistakenly thought that $ix \to \infty$. Anyways, this doesn't affect the main idea.  You missed a $-$ sign as $0$ is the lower limit.

Comment: Ok for the sign. Then all my solution is true? Please

Comment: You know the [frequency shifting property](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/signals_and_systems/fourier_transforms_properties.htm)?  I've never answered a FT question before.